# Twitter Login problems in Firebase with a React App

Tags: reactjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I am using signInWithRedirect method to login with twitter in the following react component

```
<PrimaryButton 
title={signup ? 'Sign Up with Twitter' : 'Log In with Twitter'} 
img={twitter} 
colour='twitterBlue white pointer' 
action={() => auth.signInWithRedirect(twitterAuthProvider)} />
```

(The action props just corresponds to an onClick. I'm pretty sure its not a problem with my code because I have the identical code for a facebook and google login and they work fine.)

**When I try and sign up or login I get the same mysterious error in my console "Network error while to fetch VERIFY_CREDENTIAL from TWITTER."**

This is the signup form in action https://tamurowebapp.firebaseapp.com/signup

I tried swapping signInWithRedirect for signing in with a popup and then onAuthStateChanged instead of auth.getRedirectResult() but it's all the same.

We even deleted and remade the twitter app and then reset all the keys in firebase to be safe.

Even worse the error only happens sometimes. It's not something I can replicate on demand. Much stress.

Has anyone had a similar problem and can you recommend a solution?

Comment: This is related to the OAuth exchange between the Firebase Auth backend and the Twitter token endpoint. The Twitter endpoint seems to be flaky. It would be a good idea to file a bug with Twitter about this too.

Comment: Hi Josh, I've also been noticing this issue as well. Sadly, the failure is so flaky and hard to replicate I can't quite narrow things down enough to ask Firebase to look into this further. here's to hoping they see this issue and investigate.

Comment: To help SEO for this issue, this appears related to "Network error while to fetch CODE_EXCHANGE from TWITTER."

Comment: I got a response from firebase. Not resolved yet but it's a useful update. 

"...I'd just like to inform you that there are other developers reporting this kind of issue. We already consulted this with our engineers, and upon checking with them, this case could be a known issue caused by unreliable third party endpoints and not a Firebase related issue."